# Solve indefinite integral $\int\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to evaluate
$$\int\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
I tried to use substitution $$x=tg(t)$$ and got $$\int\frac{tg(t)^6}{\cos(t)^3}dt$$

Comment: Try taking $u = \sqrt {x^2 + 1}$

Comment: A good candidate for [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) substitution. You can simplify the integrand a bit first by substituting $u=x^2$ or integrating by parts.

Comment: You have a power-counting error: it should be $\int\frac{\tan^6t\sec^2tdt}{\sec t}=\int\frac{\tan^6tdt}{\cos t}$.

Comment: Yes, you’re right, thanks

Answer (score 3):

A hyperbolic trigonometric substitution gives a quick solution.

$x = \sinh y$

The integrand becomes simply $\sinh^6 y = \frac 1{64}(e^y - e^{-y})^6$, which is easily expanded with the binomial theorem and the termwise integration is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. Substitute $x = \tan(t)$. Then, $dx = \sec^2(t)dt$. This leads to $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}=\sqrt{\tan^2(t)+1} = \sec(t)$.

Substituting these terms yields
$$
\int \frac{\tan^6(t)}{\sec(t)} \cdot \sec^2(t)dt = \int \tan^6(t)\sec(t) dt
$$

From there you can apply $\tan^2(t) = \sec^2(t) -1$ and express the integrand using $\sec^2(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

This type of integral is also known as a "Chebyshev" integral.

$$I = \int\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}dx = \int x^6(x^2 + 1)^{1/2}dx$$

Where $m = 6, n = 2, p = \frac{1}{2}$. We observe that $\frac{m+1}{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}, p \notin \mathbb{Z}$, but $\frac{m+1}{n} + p = 4 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, consider $u = (1 + x^{-2})^{1/2}$. From then on you can express it in terms of rational functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ I_n=\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx$ and integrate both sides of
$$\left(x^{n-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)’
=\frac{n x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+ \frac{(n-1) x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
to establish the reduction formula
$I_n = \frac{x^{n-1}}n\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}
$.
Then, apply it to $I_6$ three times
$$\int \frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx
=\bigg( \frac{x^5}6-\frac{5x^3}{24}+\frac{5x}{16}\bigg) \sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac5{16}I_0
$$
where $I_0= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx =\sinh^{-1}x$.

Answer (score 0):

- Euler-substitute:

$$\int \frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx \stackrel{x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}}= 128 \int \frac{t^6}{(1-t^2)^7}\,dt$$

- Reduce the numerator to a cubic, then Euler-substitute:

$$\int \frac{x^6}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \, dx \stackrel{t=x^2}= \int \frac{t^3}{2\sqrt{t^2+t}}\,dt \stackrel{t=\frac{u^2}{1-2u}}= \int \frac{u^6}{(1-2u)^4} \, du$$

The remaining integrands can be expanded into partial fractions.